# Update the value into new column in current dataframe based on another column from different dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column in my dataframe with full of messages and want to categorize them based on the substring present in that message. Well, those substrings that has to be searched in the messages are to be fetched from different dataframe(lets call it master dataframe) and my master dataframe is dynamic and based on the list in master i have to categorize in my main dataframe column

**Note : this has to work regardless of uppercase or lowercase letters**

df1 table looks like :

```
           Messages
0         Firewall_Error
1         Firewall_Error_1
2         Firewall_Error_2
3         Firewall_Error_3
4        Wifihealth_1_Info
              ...         
109       Firewall_Error_1
110       Firewall_Error_2
111       Firewall_Error_3
112      Wifihealth_1_Info
113    Wifihealth_2_Failed
```

Master_df looks like :

```
    Strings Category
0   error   Error
1   info    Information
2   failed  Warning
```

So if Master_df['Strings'][0] substring is found in Messages column of df1, map that row in df1[category] as Master_df['Category'][0] and so on..

Expected output:

df1 must look like :

```
           Messages           category
0         Firewall_Error      Error
1         Firewall_Error_1    Error
2         Firewall_Error_2    Error
3         Firewall_Error_3    Error
4        Wifihealth_1_Info    Information
              ...         
109       Firewall_Error_1    Error
110       Firewall_Error_2    Error
111       Firewall_Error_3    Error
112      Wifihealth_1_Info    Information
113    Wifihealth_2_Failed    warning
```

Codes tried :

```
for i in range(0,len(Master_df['Strings'])):
    df1['Category'] = pd.np.where(df1.Messages.str.contains(Master_df['Strings'][i]), Master_df['Category'][i]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.lower`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.lower.html)  for lowercase first, then [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) by joined `Strings` converted to `index` for possible mapping by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to new column:

```
#if need also convert Strings to lowercases
s = Master_df.set_index('Strings')['Category'].rename(index=str.lower)
pat = f'({"|".join(s.index)})'
df1['Category'] = df1['Messages'].str.lower().str.extract(pat, expand=False).map(s)
print (df1)
                Messages     Category
0         Firewall_Error        Error
1       Firewall_Error_1        Error
2       Firewall_Error_2        Error
3       Firewall_Error_3        Error
4      Wifihealth_1_Info  Information
109     Firewall_Error_1        Error
110     Firewall_Error_2        Error
111     Firewall_Error_3        Error
112    Wifihealth_1_Info  Information
113  Wifihealth_2_Failed      Warning
```

Comment: Its working fine. Although, would this even work if the cases in messages are inconsistent? coz i see usage of lower()..just confused on that operation..

Comment: @AnandThirtha - Ya, I use it for matching lowercase values from `Master_df['Strings']`

Comment: What if i have to ignore the case sensitivity all together? just match the strings and map? coz while validating with different scenarios i found few nan values which weren't mapped ..

Comment: @AnandThirtha - I add str.lower for matching more values, e.g. if omit it in sample data `Firewall_Error` cannot match with `error` - but `firewall_error` matching `error`. If some NaNs there should eb some different problem

Comment: Is there any way where i can ignore case senstivity?

Comment: @AnandThirtha - It is possible, but then no mapping because `Firewall_Error` exctract `Error` and no match by `error`, check it `import re` `print (df1['Category'] = df1['Messages'].str.lower().str.extract(pat, expand=False, flags=re.I))`

Comment: `df1['Category'] = df1['Messages'].str.lower().str.extract(pat, expand=False, flags=re.I).map(s)`

Comment: Now i have a message : 'Firewall_ERROR_2' and is not mapped into Error category.. is there any way where i can handle this?

Comment: @AnandThirtha - by my answer with `str.lower`

Comment: @AnandThirtha - Do you understand comment? [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66703834/update-the-value-into-new-column-in-current-dataframe-based-on-another-column-fr/66703859?noredirect=1#comment117913939_66703859) ?

Comment: Like i mentioned the master table can be dynamic.. 'error' in strings columns might change as 'Error' anytime..

Comment: @AnandThirtha - hmm, it has no sense, because lowercase values

Comment: @AnandThirtha - hmm, maybe need `s = Master_df.set_index('Strings')['Category'].rename(index=str.lower)`

Comment: Yes, this seems to work..thanks..
So messages can have any type.. upper or lower cases ..this should work by changing the case in master itself?

Comment: quick question - @jezrael how can i modify this code if master rows had to be combined and searched in messages column..? like what if message contains both 'Error' & 'info' substrings in it? if 'error' & 'info' both found or if 'error' & 'Warning' both found and so onn..then Category should be invalid..

Comment: @AnandThirtha - Can you post new question with this problem?

Comment: @AnandThirtha - You can show some 2-3 rows with problematic data there